# Firefox will load webpages once, but will not render page correctly when refreshed

Tags: html, firefox, cross-browser

I have created a site that seem's to work fine in Chrome, IE and Safari however in Firefox v 35.0.1 (on PC and Mac), pages will load fine the first time, but if a Ctrl-F5 refresh is done, the browser will only load parts of the page. I can't get it to reload the page again correctly unless I navigate away from the page and then navigate back to it.

Go here on Firefox 35.0.1 and try reloading the front-page (or any other page for that matter) with Ctrl-F5 a few times...
http://www.cygnusmusic.net

If you don't manage to create a broken page by refreshing it, I'd be keen to know about that too.

On re-loading firefox misses out images and styles in an inconsistent manner, or just displays a 'connection was reset' message over and over again until eventually it decides to part-load the page again. While Firefox is displaying a 'Connection was reset' message, other browsers still have no problem loading and re-loading the same pages.

If this is ultimately resolved as a server issue outside of answers to this question, then I will post any info I have regarding the solution as an answer here.

**UPDATE**
Here is a link to a video of this occurring on every page of the site, plus a broadband speedtest showing 60Mb+ download speeds...
http://youtu.be/EncGAZs9KAY
Yes, my computer is thrashing during this video, but the loading results are the same on PC's and Macs which are running properly too.

Comment: I think you have an issue with your coding, as your header image didn't appear for me correctly at all, but flashes when refreshed, then reverts back to only showing part of it. This could be a confliction with your JS as it's being called maybe?

Comment: I have previously tried - removing the parallax.min.js library and removing the link to a google api hosted web font but the problem persisted. I can get the header to load okay sometimes in firefox, but it is totally inconsistent, yet completely consistent in other browsers. The same problem can also be recreated by multiple refreshes of this page (http://cygnusmusic.net/updating.html), which is a very basic html page linking to just 4 images. However, the basic html page will load 'most' times ok, but not every time it's refreshed.

Comment: Loads everytime perfectly for me

Comment: Cool! Thanks for the feedback. This is one of the weirdest compatibility problems I've encountered. It is difficult to get updating.html to break, but I have managed it.

Comment: I've also just updated the original post with a video link showing the issue occurring.